# std::advance in c++ do not behave correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, stdlist

while i was tweaking around with std::list in c++ i used std::advance to access elements randomly.but std::advance is not working as expected.the code is as given below.

```
#include <list>
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
list<int> i;
typename list<int>::iterator t=i.begin();
i.push_front(0);
i.push_back(1);
i.push_back(2);
i.push_back(3);
cout<<*t<<" ";
advance(t,1);
cout<<*t<<" ";
advance(t,2);
cout<<*t<<" ";
}
```

the output i got is 0 0 2
but shouldn't the output be 0 1 3

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the iterator before you have added anything to the list. The line

```
typename list<int>::iterator t=i.begin();
```

is equivalent to

```
typename list<int>::iterator t=i.end();
```

`t` continues to point to the end of the list even after you add the items to the list. Hence, the first line tries to dereference the iterator

```
cout<<*t<<" "
```

is cause for undefined behavior. Anything can happen after that. There is no point trying to make sense of the output of the program after that.

To fix the problem, you should get the iterator after you add the items to the list.

```
#include <list>
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   list<int> i;
   i.push_front(0);
   i.push_back(1);
   i.push_back(2);
   i.push_back(3);
   typename list<int>::iterator t=i.begin();
   cout<<*t<<" ";
   advance(t,1);
   cout<<*t<<" ";
   advance(t,2);
   cout<<*t<<" ";
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 3
```